# Using BARD for my Personal Assistant - instead of ChatGPT

Tags: python, google-assistant-sdk, uisearchbardelegate

I can't get the BARD endpoint to work... Any one have any suggestions on how to get this to work? Below is the code:

import requests
import json
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

BARD_API_URL = "https://ai.google/bard"  # Replace with the actual Bard API endpoint
REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 10  # Set the timeout to 10 seconds – gives the system time to respond

def listen_to_microphone(device_index=None):
recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

```
try:
    with sr.Microphone(device_index=device_index) as source:
        print("Using microphone:", source)
        print("Listening...")
        audio = recognizer.listen(source, timeout=5)  # Set a timeout of 5 seconds
        print("Audio recorded successfully.")
except OSError:
    print("Error: Microphone not found or inaccessible.")
    return None

try:
    print("Recognizing...")
    text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
    print("You said:", text)
    return text
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Could not understand audio.")
    return None
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results; {0}".format(e))
    return None
```

def get_bard_response(query):
headers = {
"Content-Type": "application/json"
}
data = {
"text": query
}

```
try:
    # Modified the requests.post() function call to include the timeout parameter
    response = requests.post(BARD_API_URL, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data), timeout=REQUEST_TIMEOUT)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Check if the response is a valid JSON object
        if json.loads(response.content):
            return response.json().get('response', 'Could not fetch response from Bard.')
        else:
            return "Error: Invalid JSON response from Bard."
    else:
        return f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}"
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    return "Error: Request timed out."
```

def speak(text):
engine = pyttsx3.init()

```
try:
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: Could not speak text:", e)
```

if **name** == "**main**":
speak("Hello! How can I assist you today?")

```
while True:
    user_input = listen_to_microphone()

    if user_input:
        if user_input.lower() == "exit":
            speak("Goodbye!")
            break

        # Call Bard API to get a response based on the user's input
        bard_response = get_bard_response(user_input)
        speak(bard_response)
```

Well, I have tried different versions of using Bard endpoints, and I can't get them to work - I usually get a 404 error code. I am aware that the BARD endpoint is probably not correct, but I can't find an endpoint that works.

Comment: 404 means not found, double check your API URL.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).